Formula to find the median of different tasks having different count by using unique task
I have a problem where I need to calculate the median of a table with two columns: task and count.



Task
count




A1
23


A1
20


A2
15


A2
10


A2



A3
5


A3
7


A3
12



The formula should be an array function, so that if the row count increases, it should calculate the median by taking the first unique task first and then for the second unique task and so on.

Welcome. Please do read [ask] and share a test sheet so as you can be easier helped.

What would be your desired output from given data?

To get the average per each task, use query(), like this:
=query(A1:B, "select A, avg(B) where A is not null group by A", 1)

See query().

I don't think Median is available in Query, but you could construct your own:
=let(u,unique(tocol(A2:A,1)),hstack(u,map(u,lambda(f,median(filter(B2:B,A2:A=f))))))


The average of task A3 is 8, the median is 7.
